# WPF - Command in a MenuItem in a DataTemplate

Tags: wpf, datatemplate, command, menuitem

I have a DataTemplate containing an Image. To the Image I added a ContextMenu with a MenuItem. To the MenuItem I associated a command. I then handle the command in the view using the DataTemplate.

In the CanExecute handler I have e.CanExecute = true. But the Executed handler is never executed. If I remove the Command assignment the MenuItem, the Menu is shown correctly when I right-click on the Image.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: The exact context  and the xaml code would greatly add to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out - After e.CanExecute = true; I had a MessageBox.Show, and this was preventing the Executed from being called. I am not sure why though.